# Can I use httpclient 3.1 and 4.0 together?

Tags: java, httpclient

Will using httpclient 3.1 and 4.0 together cause any problems?

Comment: I edited your question to make it more answerable and less vague - but why do you want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be any problem ,until unless you point ot higher visersion jars as those can contain both the versions (lower and higher)